# Transpose rows into columns SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, pivot, sql-server-2014

I have a CSV file with 51 columns.

In this order, there is a UID Column, Serial Column, Date column and 48 columns for each 30 minute segment of the day (from 00:30 through to 00:00). Each day has a new row.
So it looks like:

```
UID | Serial | Date       | Val_0030 | Val_0100 | Val_0130 | ..... | Val_0000
123 | 123456 | 2016-01-02 | 56.2     | 23.25    | 32.8     | ..... | 86.23
```

I need to transpose this data into 4 columns, so that each half hour has a UID, Serial and Date column. In other words I need to run down instead of across.

To look like this:

```
UID | Serial | 2016-01-02 00:30 | Value
```

Rather that each day having a new row as it currently does, I will determine that Val_0130 for example will determine that the time is 01:30 and will concat with the date

I have tried using pivot and unpivot without any success. Can anyone advise the best approach to do this.

Comment: are you generating UID and serial?  if so, why can't you group on your date field at the interval you require and generate them?  but, if UID and serial exist their names lend me to think they are uniques...  how are you dealing with choosing a distinct for your 30 minute grouping?

Comment: The UID and serial are provided by the customer to identify the device. The UID is a number that locates the device in an asset register and the serial number is just the serial number. I will try grouping and see what happens.

Comment: you'll need to deal with multiple instances of UID and serial per time interval group then

Comment: or you can include them in your groupings if you need that detail, but you'll have multiple occurrences of the same 30 minute intervals.  by device basically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `UNPIVOT` and then cut up the column name `Val_0130` to add to datetime to get the desired result.  This way you will only have to write the 48 columns in one spot.

here is some test data:

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (UID INT, Serial INT, Date DATETIME, Val_0030 MONEY, Val_0100 MONEY, Val_0130 MONEY, Val_0000 MONEY)
INSERT INTO @Table (UID, Serial, Date, Val_0030, Val_0100, Val_0130, Val_0000)
VALUES
(123, 123456, '2016-01-02',56.2,23.25,12.34,86.23)
,(231, 234561, '2016-01-05',26.2,13.25,23.45,106.23)
,(312, 345612, '2016-01-07',76.2,3.25,34.56,1010.56)
```

And the Query

```
SELECT
    UID
    ,Serial
    ,DateWithTime = [Date] + CAST((SUBSTRING(ColumnNames,5,2) + ':' + RIGHT(ColumnNames,2)) AS DATETIME)
    ,Value
FROM
    @Table t
    UNPIVOT (
       Value
       FOR ColumnNames IN (Val_0030, VAL_0100, Val_0130, VAL_0000)
    ) u
```

And if you don't want to type out all 48 columns, like I wouldn't want to, just run this query and copy and past the result into the `ColumnNames IN ()` section of the above query.

```
DECLARE @ColString VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @DT DATETIME = '00:00'

WHILE @DT < '1900-01-02 00:00:00.000'
BEGIN
    IF LEN(@ColString) > 0
    BEGIN
       SET @ColString += ','
    END

    SET @ColString += 'Val_' + FORMAT(@DT,'HHmm')

    SET @DT = DATEADD(MINUTE,30,@DT)
END

SELECT @ColString
```

Comment: Hi Matt, that worked a treat, wha tis the difference between pivot and unpivot?

Comment: UNPIVOT is when you want to take columns and make them rows while PIVOT is for when you want to take rows and make them columns so they are the reverse of each other.  In your case you had a table that was already pivoted so you wanted to unpivot it

Answer (score 1):

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5510627/matt) provides a good answer with UNPIVOT.  On platforms where that's not an option, you can get the same effect using a cross join and a case statement.  Create a table of half-hours, and produce the values with

```
select ...
       , case hh.time  when '00:00' then VAL_0000
                       when '00:30' then Val_0030
                       when '01:00' then Val_0100
                       when '01:30' then Val_0130
         ...
         end as Value
from data cross join "half-hours" as hh
```